# LPc11u68 Recognized as a USB mass storage either when programmed in HID class

Tags: c, usb, hid, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

When I connected a newbie LPC11u68 to USB port,it recognized in windows as an USB mass storage device.When I programmed LPCOPEN HID example by Flash magic to it,after resetting the board,my PC can't recognized it.Only when I pulled down PIO0_1(ISP selection pin)it still recognized as a Mass storage device.???

**EDIT:**

with adding a 470r resistor to the USB_DP line ,all problems were vanished and MCU correctly recognized by PC as a HID device.

Answer (score 0):

> When I connected a newbie LPC11u68 to USB port,it recognized in windows as an USB mass storage device

The good news: The hardware works. The (mask-) ROM bootloader presents itself as mass storage device.

> When I programmed LPCOPEN HID example by Flash magic to it,after resetting the board,my PC can't recognized it

The bad news: This program does not work. There are many possible causes, for example:

- You compiled for the wrong processor type
- The program expects different hardware to be present

Comment: I used it's owned LPCOPEN HID example,I compiled it successfully with LPCXPRESSO & it's required hardware is designed well based on the LPCXPRESSO board's schematic